# Objective C - functions (not sure how to explain this one)

Tags: objective-c, ios, function, syntax, cocos2d-iphone

I'm working on an iOS app with Cocos2D and I'm running into a lot of situations where I want to do something with a slight delay so I use a line of code like this:

```
[self scheduleOnce:@selector(do_something) delay:10];
```

The stuff that happens in `do_something` is only one line of code though.
Is there a way for me to define the function right in that line where I schedule it?

When I used to program with jQuery this is similar in what I'm trying to achieve:

```
$("a").click(function() {
  alert("Hello world!");
});
```

See how function() is defined right there?  Is there a way to do this in Objective-C?
Also, is there a name for this?  For future searches?  Because I find this hard to explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `dispatch_after` to execute a block after a certain amount of time.

```
int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    /* code to be executed on the main queue after delay */
});
```

I would refer to it as a time dispatched block.

**EDIT**: How to dispatch it only once.

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    /* code to be executed once */
});
```

So in your case:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    int64_t delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        /* code to be executed on the main queue after delay */
    })
});
```

Comment: I'll be trying this out for the next few minutes. Thanks for what term you'd use to refer to it.  That was another main thing I wanted to get from this question.

Comment: This seems to be executing repeatedly, every 2 seconds in this case.  I only want this to execute once.

Comment: It only executes once. You are placing it in a function that is repeating. See my edit, which shows how to dispatch it only once.

Comment: My bad, you were right. I was placing it in a repeating function.  Very informative though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Cocos2D you can also take advantage of the CCDelayTime method and combine it in a CCSequence to achieve your desired effect.  Something along the lines of:

```
id delayAction = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:10];
id callSelector = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(do_something)];
[self runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:delayAction two:callSelector]];
```

Or you can also use the CCCallBlock so you don't have to write a separate method to do_something, just put it in a block.

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:delayAction two:[CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
// do something here
           }]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to declare the method "do_something" as

```c
-(void)do_something {
    //Your implementation here
}
```

In this case you can add as many line as possible for do_something method.

@selector(do_something) is a command to execute a method in your class.

Comment: This is what I've been doing.  But I have so many of these that it seems unnecessary to have to define a function for one line of code.

Comment: Do you want to add a delay before, after or in between of a method? If you want to add a delay before executing a method you can use [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];

Comment: Well what I want is somewhat of an "anonymous selector" which doesn't exist as far as i know.  I don't want to define a method for do_something because it is only one line of code.

Comment: May I know the "one line of code" in your current "do_something" method? Does the "one line of code" call another method? If yes, you can use [self performSelector:@selector(another_method) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f]; If the "one line of code" is [self method_A]; you can use [self performSelector:@selector(method_A) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];

Comment: Daniel's solution works well.  My `do_something` represents the many different one line things ranging from scene transitions to making on CCSprite invisible.